# Create a function which returns a boolean in React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, boolean

I have some conditional styling based on if a certain value exist. The value can exist or can be `null`

```
background-color: ${myPropValue.myKey !== null ? 'pink' : 'green'};
```

This works fine. However I need to add some more conditional styling based on the same logic in this file.

I try to create a function which I can reuse:

```
const hasMyPropValue = ({ myPropValue }: Pick<MyType, 'myPropValue'>) =>
  myPropValue.myKey !== null;
```

When I want to use it like `background-color: ${hasMyPropValue() ? 'pink' : 'green'};` I get a linting error: `Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)`

I just want it to return true or false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial function was almost correct:

```
const hasMyPropValue = ({ myPropValue }: Pick<MyType, 'myPropValue'>) =>
  myPropValue.myKey !== null;
```

But here I check if type is not of type `null` and if it's `undefined`. That doesn't work in this case.

I changed the comparison operator (`!=` instead of `!==`) and then my function works. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript).

```
const hasMyPropValue = ({ myPropValue }: Pick<MyType, 'myPropValue'>) =>
 myPropValue.myKey != null;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my opinion, you define css properties with a class name. When `${myPropValue.myKey !== null` then you add particular class what you want. From this you able to define multiple properties.

Comment: `className = {myPropValue.myKey !== null? YourClassName: defaultClassName} ` In CSS you define these required classes.

Answer (score 0):

> I try to create a function which I can reuse: ... I don't want to pass any argument I just want it to return true or false?

With the two statements you made, the `myPropValue` has to either be passed an argument or be available in the scope where `hasMyPropValue` is located because you've typed it as required.

Answer (score 0):

When you do not want to pass any arguments, then you can define the params as optional parameters like below and also can provide default values to the parameters.

```js
function hasMyPropValue({
  myPropValue = {
    myKey: null
  }
}: {
  myPropValue? : Object
} = {}) {
  return myPropValue.myKey !== null;
}

console.log(hasMyPropValue() ? 'pink': 'green');
```

Comment: thanks. And when I pass an argument like `${hasMyPropValue({myPropValue}) ? 'pink' : 'green'};` can we write a less verbose function?

Comment: We can create another function which makes a call to `hasMyPropValue` to get the respective class name.

Comment: If it is just a styling change, then this approach is good enough.

Comment: What I meant previously was, if `${hasMyPropValue({myPropValue}) ? 'pink' : 'green'};` this is the condition you are using more than once, then you can create another function say `getColor` which returns either `pink` or `green` based on the return value of `hasMyPropValue`.